# Download images from azure storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I want to download all images in a folder from a container i tried to download one image and it works, i need just to put the name of the image (Exemple: download_Image(bird.png)). It works only with this path path="files/exemple.png".

```
def download_Image(blobname):
 blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(azure_storage_setting)

 blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="images", blob=blobname)
 try:
    path="files/exemple.png"
    download_file_path = os.path.join(path)
    message='Download done!'
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(download_file_path), exist_ok=True)
    with open(download_file_path, "wb") as download_file:
        download_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())

 except ResourceNotFoundError:
    print("No blob found.")
    message = "No blob found."

 return message
download_Image(a)
```

I just want to download images with original names so i changed the path like this path = "files" and i had this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden: ''

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce in my environment works fine successfully.***

I have created a path folder along with sample images in blob storage like below.

[image]

To download all images in a folder from a container in azure blob storage make use of below code to execute.

```py
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient    
MY_CONNECTION_STRING = "CONNECTION_STRING"
MY_BLOB_CONTAINER = "name"    eplace with the local folder where you want files to be downloaded
LOCAL_BLOB_PATH = "Blobsss"    
BLOBNAME="test"
class AzureBlobFileDownloader:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Intializing AzureBlobFileDownloader")      
        self.blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(MY_CONNECTION_STRING)
        self.my_container = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(MY_BLOB_CONTAINER)
   def save_blob(self, file_name, file_content):
            # Get full path to the file 
        download_file_path = os.path.join(LOCAL_BLOB_PATH, file_name)
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(download_file_path), exist_ok=True)
        with open(download_file_path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(file_content)
    
    
    def download_all_blobs_in_container(self):
        my_blobs = self.my_container.list_blobs()
        for blob in my_blobs:
            print(blob.name)
            bytes = self.my_container.get_blob_client(blob).download_blob().readall()
            self.save_blob(blob.name, bytes) 
   
azure_blob_file_downloader = AzureBlobFileDownloader()
azure_blob_file_downloader.download_all_blobs_in_container()
```

[image]

All images in the folder path are downloaded successfully like below.

***Output***: [image]